# Display elements in list with a counter of three

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pagination

There is this bootstrap pagination and it shows all the 10 list items,
although I can hide rest of elements and show only three but when I 
click next all the elements gets displayed , I just want to show 
next three elements and hide the previous and then next three and so on
with previous and next buttons.

This is the css :

```
<style>
    .hide {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

This is the HTML :

```
<div class="page">
    <nav>
        <ul class="pagination pagination-lg">
            <li class="page-item">
                <span class="page-link prev" href="#" aria-label="Previous">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </span>
            </li>
            <li class="page-item list"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
            <li class="page-item list"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
            <li class="page-item list"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
            <li class="page-item list"><a class="page-link" href="#">4</a></li>
            <li class="page-item list"><a class="page-link" href="#">5</a></li>
            <li class="page-item list"><a class="page-link" href="#">6</a></li>
            <li class="page-item list"><a class="page-link" href="#">7</a></li>
            <li class="page-item list"><a class="page-link" href="#">8</a></li>
            <li class="page-item list"><a class="page-link" href="#">9</a></li>
            <li class="page-item list"><a class="page-link" href="#">10</a></li>
            <li class="page-item">
                <span class="page-link next" href="#" aria-label="Next">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

This is the jquery :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".list").slice(3).addClass('hide');
        $("li:last-child").removeClass('hide');
        $('.next').click(function() {
            $('ul li').removeClass('hide');
        });
    });
</script>
```

**This is the  JS fiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/5d7kz732/**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you had mostly nothing within your `$('.next').click(function() {`.

I added a `var position = 0;` to track current position and add 3 to it, whenever we click.

`if(list.length < position + 3) return`  check, so that we don't go further the the length off all elements.

```
 list.slice(0, position).addClass('hide');
 list.slice(position + 3).addClass('hide');
```

to hide the rest.

To make it work for the previous button

```
   $('.prev').click(function() {
     if(0 > position - 3) return position = 0
     position-=3;
     $('ul li').removeClass('hide');
     list.slice(0, position).addClass('hide');
     list.slice(position + 3).addClass('hide');
     $("li:last-child").removeClass('hide');
   });
```

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var list = $(".list")
   list.slice(3).addClass('hide');
   $("li:last-child").removeClass('hide');

   var position = 0;

   $('.next').click(function() {
     if (list.length < position + 3) return
     position += 3;
     $('ul li').removeClass('hide');
     list.slice(0, position).addClass('hide');
     list.slice(position + 3).addClass('hide');
     $("li:last-child").removeClass('hide');
   });

   $('.prev').click(function() {
     if (0 > position - 3) return position = 0
     position -= 3;
     $('ul li').removeClass('hide');
     list.slice(0, position).addClass('hide');
     list.slice(position + 3).addClass('hide');
     $("li:last-child").removeClass('hide');
   });

 });
```

```css
.hide {
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page">
  <nav>
    <ul class="pagination pagination-lg">
      <li class="page-item">
        <span class="page-link prev" href="#" aria-label="Previous">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </span>
      </li>
      <li class="page-item list"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
      <li class="page-item list"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
      <li class="page-item list"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
      <li class="page-item list"><a class="page-link" href="#">4</a></li>
      <li class="page-item list"><a class="page-link" href="#">5</a></li>
      <li class="page-item list"><a class="page-link" href="#">6</a></li>
      <li class="page-item list"><a class="page-link" href="#">7</a></li>
      <li class="page-item list"><a class="page-link" href="#">8</a></li>
      <li class="page-item list"><a class="page-link" href="#">9</a></li>
      <li class="page-item list"><a class="page-link" href="#">10</a></li>
      <li class="page-item">
        <span class="page-link next" href="#" aria-label="Next">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer works but you should explain what you've done so far.

Comment: I can iterate over to the next elements with next but cannot go back to previous elements , can you Please help in that too.

Comment: @aashi0001 yes, it is pretty much the same, just in reverse. let me show you

Comment: @arcs it would be great id you can implement that as well because, the counter cannot go down beyond the 1,2,3 elements.